# SDL: Move created Fullscreen window to another display

Tags: sdl, fullscreen, sdl-2, multiple-monitors

I am using SDL2 (2.0.5) and faced following question:

**How to move created Fullscreen window to another display ??**

It looks like *SDL_SetWindowPosition()* works only in Windowed mode.

Right now I'm using following workaround:

- Change window's fullscreen state to Windowed (using
  *SDL_SetWindowFullscreen()*)
- Move window to another display
- Change window's fullscreen state back to Fullscreen

But I feel there is a better way of doing this, right ?

Comment: Are you using `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` or `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP`?

Comment: @genpfault, both. I have an option in my game, so player can select which mode is preferable. And in both cases SDL_SetWindowPosition() has no effect.